# this.props.navigation.navigate doesn't navigate to other screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a tab navigator and stack navigator. Here is the structure;

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      auth: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
          auth: {
            screen: AuthScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
              header: null
            }
          },
          login: {
            screen: LoginScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
              title: 'Login',
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#3f2141'
              }
            }
          },
          newAccount: {
            screen: NewAccountScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
              title: 'Create an Account',
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#3f2141'
              },
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontSize: 20
              }
            }
          }
        }),
      },
      main: { screen: MainScreen }
    })
```

No problem when trying to pass from auth screen to login screen or new account screen. But I am trying to pass from new account screen to main screen if creating account is succesful. Here is the action code that try to do this;

```
export const createUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return(dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_USER });

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => createUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => createUserFail(dispatch));
  };
};

const createUserFail = (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_USER_FAIL })
};

const createUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CREATE_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  });
  navigateToMainScreen();
};

const navigateToMainScreen = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('main')
};
```

But navigate function does not work here, so user create account but screen doesnt change. I figure it out and may be the reason is one new account screen is in stack navigator while main screen is in tab navigator but I cant solve the problem.

Comment: Is the method `navigateToMainScreen` actually being called after the `dispatch`? Is `props.navigation` object set in your component? Is there a reason you're not using `createSwitchNavigator` for the authentication flow?

Comment: Why not trying `this.props.navigation.goBack()` ? It is not clear how your project is structured. Note that you need to pass props if it is separated.

Comment: @UzairA. Yes it is called after dispatch. Navigation object is set in app.js, this is another component.

Comment: @SirKoswara because it is an authentication flow and i dont want it to go back.

Comment: @wierdo then you should reset the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to call `this.props.navigation.navigate` in a separate component, the `navigation` prop must be passed to it first. Let's say you want to use `navigation` in `NewAccountScreen` then pass the prop like this:

```
<NewAccountScreen navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

in the parent component where the `NewAccountScreen` needs to be rendered.

Another way to use `navigation` anywhere in your app is using `withNavigation`. Following the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class NewAccountScreen extends React.Component {
  // your code including the call to this.props.navigation.navigate()
  // ...
}

// withNavigation returns a component that wraps NewAccountScreen
// and passes in the navigation prop:

export default withNavigation(NewAccountScreen);
```

> Using this approach, you can render NewAccountScreen anywhere in your app
>   without passing in a navigation prop explicitly and it will work as
>   expected.

On a side note, I highly recommend you to rethink your router structure. You may have your reasons but putting the auth and main screens in the same `createBottomTabNavigator` doesn't make much sense to me. There's [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) regarding authentication flows using `createSwitchNavigator` which will make your life easier. Consider giving it a shot before your project becomes more complicated!

Comment: I actually want to navigate in createUserSuccess action creator. Simply, after successful signup, it should be directed to main screen. I think it is the right place to navigate, right?

Comment: That depends on where the `createUserSuccess` method is contained. Is it defined within a React Component (like `NewAccountScreen`)? If yes, then you can use a solution from the answer above. If no, then you can check for `CREATE_USER_SUCCESS` in the parent component and handle the navigation to main screen from there.

Comment: createUserSuccess la not in the component. I figure out a way,  if createUserSuccess is completed i will get user prop via payload then connect it to parent component with mapStateProps. Then if user is not null i will call navigation with this.props.navigation.navigate(‘main’). I will plan to call it in the componentDidMount, what do u think? Am i in the right path?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use some kind of information externally in a component to use the `navigation` prop and navigate to some other screen, but I am not sure if `componentDidMount` is the best place to call it. It depends on the structure of your project.

Comment: I did it in componentWillReceiveProps